# Set the maxDate and minDate in cordova datepicker plugin

Tags: cordova, datepicker, maxdate, mindate

I am trying to add Native Date picker in my project and the plugin is below,

1st pulgin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/DURK/cordova-datepicker-plugin
```

(or)
2st plugin:

```
cordova local plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker
```

The 2-plugins are working well and i want to set maxDate and minDate for that Datepicker. But, i can't get any solution for that.

Give any suggestion for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[VitaliiBlagodir-cordova-plugin-datepicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) supports setting of maxDate and minDate.

It is supported in **iOS** and **android**.

Documentation suggests that

> minDate is a Date object for iOS and an integer for Android, so you
>   need to account for that when using the plugin.

`minDate` and `maxDate` must be `DATE objects for iOS`,

Both attributes should be `integer for android`. so need to parse Date object with

`Date.parse(new Date())` or `(new Date()).valueOf()`

Answer (score 0):

```
     import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
     constructor(private platform: Platform) {}
```

at date picker show method

```
     maxDate = (this.platform.is('android')) ? (new Date(endtime)).valueOf() : new Date(endtime)
```